# Why do MathJax piecewise function (case blocks) not render correctly?

Tags: support, mathjax, markdown

When using [**MathJax**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) I thought that `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}` would have each case printed on a separate line.

Instead, the separate cases all all listed on the same line, when I look at it.

How do we fix this?

```latex
\sigma(n) =
\begin{cases}
n/2,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\   
3n+1, & \text{if $n$ is odd}  \\
\end{cases}
```

[image: SCREEN CAPTURE OF BADLY FORMATTED RENDERED OUTPUT]

$
\sigma(n) =
\begin{cases}
n/2,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\   
3n+1, & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
\end{cases}
$

Comment: The MathJax in this question displays in two lines for me.

Comment: Plus 1, can't reproduce here.